Decipher syntax of bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://www.example.com/install.sh)"
Goal: Understand the syntax of the below Bash command specifically the purpose of "$" & the parentheses
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
The command appears to download and run a Bash script for installing Homebrew. bash -c "xxx" executes the command xxx as though typed into terminal.
Searching in google and stackoverflow using "bash -c "$(curl -" gave the below which was helpful but did not address $ and ().
text
Reading the man page for bash -c
If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are
arguments  after  the  string, they are assigned to the positional parameters,
starting with $0.
I do not understand the above man page excerpt.

I want to understand the process. If I type curl -fsSL https://example.com/install.sh on the command line in bash, install.sh downloads. If I type bash -c "echo 'hi'", hi appears. So does $(curl -...) equate to a line by line substitution of commands in the script?. If line 1 of the script is "echo hi" and line 2 "echo hello", then does the above command download one line of the script, execute bash -c "echo hi" and then download the next line and execute bash -c "echo hello"? I see the output of curl as a downloaded file. What in the above command says go line by line? Is it the $?

The $(…) is a command substitution. It runs what is in the parentheses, and substitutes its output into the command line in which the $(…) appeared.
In this case, the curl will fetch that installation script, thereby supplying the contents to the bash -c command.
This happens to be a relatively easy way of running a script fetched from a remote server. In this case, it installs Homebrew.

As an aside, I would be wary of using this sort of “run a script found on the internet” command unless you are extremely confident of the source that provided this command line (and, by inference, the script to which it points). You are telling your computer to just blithely run a script that someone else provided. If from some unscrupulous source, the script could do all sorts of bad things. In this case, Homebrew is a ubiquitous macOS tool and is trustworthy, so you’re OK, but be aware of the risks of this pattern in general.
